# Pass values as parameters if not null or empty Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have text values I retrieve from text inputs. I want to allow the user to not fill in these inputs. But if the user has not filled one or more values I want to display default values for these inputs.

I have a data class that looks something like this:

```
@Parcelize
data class Profile(
    val firstName: String = "",
    val lastName: String = "",
    val description: String = "",
    val imageUri: String = ""
) : Parcelable
```

On click I call a method from my ViewModel class and pass it the current input values which is then persisted using a Repository class:

```
viewModel.createProfile(
   etFirstName.text.toString(),
   etLastName.text.toString(),
   etProfileDescription.text.toString(),
   profileImageUri.toString()
)


// The createProfile function itself
fun createProfile(
    firstName: String = "John",
    lastName: String = "Doe",
    description: String = "Default Description",
    imageUri: String = ""
) {
    val profile = Profile(firstName, lastName, description, imageUri)
    // Persist data
}
```

In a another fragment I set some UI data using this persisted data like this:

```
private fun observeProfile() {
    viewModel.getProfile()

    viewModel.profile.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        val profile = it
        tvName.text = getString(R.string.profile_name, profile.firstName, profile.lastName)
        tvDescription.text = profile.description
        ivProfileImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(profile.imageUri))
    })
}
```

---

So currently `createProfile` expects 4 arguments. I'm able to pass less because I have optional parameters, but how can I conditionally pass arguments to `createProfile` based on if the value is non null or empty. I can of course create checks for each value, but what is the best way to approach this?

**Update**

I don't think I was clear enough in my original question, because I don't only pass values from text inputs to `createProfile`. `profileImageUri` is a class variable of type `Uri?` and is initially set to `null`. The user can select an image and this variable is updated with the image data. The reason I'm passing and storing the image data as a String is because all the profile data also gets persisted to Firestore so Strings are easier to work with.

Comment: i think you'd need a custom setter for each field, that way you can still pass through and just handle _what_ is passed through, although i'm not sure if that's possible with a data class, i don't think it is, i also can't think of a better solution than just checking every value, which is probably redundant but the simplest solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compared to your own answer, I'd create a helper function

```
fun CharSequence?.ifNullOrEmpty(default: String) = if (this.isNullOrEmpty()) default else this.toString()
```

And use it as

```
viewModel.createProfile(
    etFirstName.text.ifNullOrEmpty("John"),
    etLastName.text.ifNullOrEmpty("Doe"),
    etProfileDescription.text.ifNullOrEmpty("Default Description"),
    profileImageUri.ifNullOrEmpty("Default Uri")
)
```

EDIT: given the update, I'd consider

```
fun Any?.ifNullOrEmpty(default: String) = 
    if (this == null || (this is CharSequence && this.isEmpty())) 
        default 
    else 
        this.toString()
```

Comment: I like this idea, but this doesn't work as etSomething.text returns a value of type Editable?. So `toString` needs to be called on all these variables. But a problem with `toString` is that if `profileImageUri` or another thing I pass is actually `null` Kotlin will make it a String  `null`. So `isNullOrEmpty` will not work, because the String is not empty and not null. So it would also need to check for `null` the String.

Comment: Please see the edit. If I understood you correctly, the second part ("But a problem with toString is that if profileImageUri or another thing I pass is actually null Kotlin will make it a String null") applies if you call something like `etFirstName.text.toString().ifNullOrEmpty("John")`, this solution should avoid it.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough in my original question. I should've specified that `profileImageUri` is of type `Uri?`. But I created another similar function to handle this, so as long as I don't need to handle a lot of different data types I think this is a good approach.

Comment: If you only need to check `CharSequence`s for something other than null, you could keep a single function as in the last edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround.

Turns out it's possible to pass `if-else` statements as parameters, because `if` statements are expressions in Kotlin:

```
viewModel.createProfile(
    if (!etFirstName.text.isNullOrEmpty()) etFirstName.text.toString() else "John",
    if (!etLastName.text.isNullOrEmpty()) etLastName.text.toString() else "Doe",
    if (!etProfileDescription.text.isNullOrEmpty()) etProfileDescription.text.toString() else "Default Description",
    if (profileImageUri != null) profileImageUri.toString() else ""
)
```

Using this approach I also don't have to set default values for my `data class` variables and for my `createProfile` function parameters.

I additionally added a check in my `observeProfile` function so if `profileImageUri` is null it won't try to set the image:

```
// ...
if (profile.imageUri.isNotEmpty()) {
    ivProfileImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(profile.imageUri))
}
// ...
```

---

My initial idea doesn't seem to be possible using a data class. It does seem to be possible using a regular class and `varargs`but it has problems:

```
@Parcelize
class Profile(
    vararg val params: String
) : Parcelable

...

val params = arrayOfValues.filter{ !it.isNullOrBlank() } // filter out all unwanted data
val profile = Profile(*params) // pass every param separately using spread operator
```

Main problem here is that the parameters themselves are obfuscated. I can still get the reference to individual parameters using an index and do stuff with them, but it doesn't work as nicely.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want to use is the [Elvis Operator in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator): `?:`.

```
val test = exampleExpression ?: "alternative value"
```

> If the expression to the left of `?:` is **not null**, the elvis operator returns it, otherwise it returns the expression to the right. Note that the right-hand side expression is evaluated only if the left-hand side is null.

```
viewModel.createProfile(
   etFirstName.text.toString() ?: "John",
   etLastName.text.toString() ?: "Doe",
   etProfileDescription.text.toString() ?: "Default Description",
   profileImageUri.toString() ?: "Default Uri"
)
```

Comment: I think the problem with this is that because of the `toString` calls it will always return the left side, because Strings are non-nullable. So I don't think I can handle an EditText being empty this way. Unless I create variables that store the string if it is not empty and otherwise store null. But then I have to create a check for each property I want to pass.